# Oracle user created information

Tags: oracle, data-dictionary

Is it possible to determine what user created another user's account in Oracle database?

I have two types of users in database:

- Users having system and object privileges
- Users having only system privileges

I can find the owner of all users having system and object privileges.

```
select distinct d.username,d.account_status,t.privilege,t.owner 
from dba_users d,dba_tab_privs t where d.username=t.grantee
and d.account_status='OPEN';
```

But this query doesn't fetch the users having only system Privileges. Please help how to find the owner of all those users having only system privileges?

Comment: `dba_tab_privs.owner` lists the _table_ owner, not the _user_ owner.

Answer (score 0):

DBA_USERS (Table) will give you access to WHEN your user was created, but AFAIK the only way to get WHO created your user is if auditing is turned on.

This also requires you to have access to the DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL table.

```
SELECT OS_USERNAME,
   USERNAME AS USER_WHO_CREATED_YOU,
   USERHOST,
   TERMINAL,
   TIMESTAMP,
   OBJ_NAME AS USER_CREATED,
   ACTION_NAME
 FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL
 WHERE 
TIMESTAMP > SYSDATE-90
AND ACTION_NAME ='CREATE USER'
--AND OBJ_NAME = 'YOURUSERNAMEGOESHERE'
```

Further Reading: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3056.htm#i1619732

Comment: Dear, I am not interested to find the os-user, I wants to find who have created my database user
?

Comment: I tried the bellow Query and it works:                                                                     SELECT DISTINCT table_name, PRIVILEGE,owner
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE grantee = 'MKHISHKI';   because this user have object privillage and my user don't have object privillages. Please help

Comment: @RahmanGurbaz my query is not limited to OS_USERNAME.  That's just one of the columns that it returns.  The USERNAME column will return who created your user.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to determine what user created another user's account in Oracle database?

If Auditing is configured, then yes, you probably can.

However, I'm not sure that's what you're *really* after.

> ... this query doesn't fetch the users having only system Privileges ...

**Tab**le (and some other) Privileges are held in ???_**TAB**_PRIVS.

**Role**-based Privileges are held in ???_**ROLE**_PRIVS.

**Sys**tem Privileges are held in ???_**SYS**_PRIVS.

> ... this user have object privileges and my user don't have ...

Ah ha!

So *someone else* has access to something that you think *you* should have as well.

I would *guess* that you have an individual or, better, a Team that handle user account creation and the granting of permissions.  *Those* are the people you need to be talking to because, even if you can find out which privileges [you think] you are "lacking", you *won't* have the privilege to grant those privileges to yourself!